# How to Auto stop speech recognition if user stop speaking

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am working on Bot app and here I have 2 features

- Speech to Text
- Text to Speech

Both are working as expected but I want to detect that when user stop speaking at that time I want to stop detection and send that data to server.

Is there any way to get that user is not speaking ?

I am using below code for speech detection :

```
// Starts an AVAudio Session
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    [audioSession setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];

    // Starts a recognition process, in the block it logs the input or stops the audio
    // process if there's an error.
    recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
    AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode;
    recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES;
    recognitionTask = [speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        BOOL isFinal = NO;
        if (result) {
            // Whatever you say in the microphone after pressing the button should be being logged
            // in the console.
            NSLog(@"RESULT:%@",result.bestTranscription.formattedString);
            self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString;
            self.inputToolbar.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
            isFinal = !result.isFinal;
        }
        if (error) {
            if (audioEngine != NULL) {
                [audioEngine stop];
                [inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];
                recognitionRequest = nil;
                recognitionTask = nil;
            }
        }
    }];

    // Sets the recording format
    AVAudioFormat *recordingFormat = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0]; //[[AVAudioFormat alloc] initStandardFormatWithSampleRate:44100 channels:1];
    [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recordingFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
        [recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
    }];

    // Starts the audio engine, i.e. it starts listening.
    [audioEngine prepare];
    [audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];
    NSLog(@"Say Something, I'm listening");
```

Let me know if any one required more detail on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you got solution, using Pushpendra. @CodeChanger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using this:

```
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
NSTimer *levelTimer;
double lowPassResults;

-(void)configureRecorder{
    // AVAudioSession already set in your code, so no need for these 2 lines.
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                          nil];

    NSError *error;

    lowPassResults = 0;

    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

    if (recorder) {
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        [recorder record];
        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.05 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    } else
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
}


- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];

    const double ALPHA = 0.05;
    double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
    lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;  

    NSLog(@"lowPassResults: %f",lowPassResults);

    // Use here a threshold value to stablish if there is silence or speech
    if (lowPassResults < 0.1) {
        NSLog(@"Silence");
    } else if(lowPassResults > 0.5){
        NSLog(@"Speech");
    }
}
```

**Reference:** 
http://codedrago.com/q/200783/ios-objective-c-speech-recognition-how-to-detect-speech-start-on-ios-speech-api

Comment: Its working as expected but I have one question that will it affect on memory management as we are using speech to text API so its already consuming more memory and CPU for network call and recording so give ur valuable comments on this if possible, By the way Thanks for the code.

Comment: i am using this code and its working fine in my application.  you are using recorder only for detect silence so i don't think it will consume more memory. only one thing you need to manage timer and recorder. invalidate timer and stop recorder when your task is done.

Comment: Yes let me give a try to this code and go live let see what happen but as per ur exp I don't think so it will consume more memory. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Pushpendra how to convert speech to text using this ??

Comment: @Pushpendra how where to call configureRecorder in while start listening. I am not able to figure out. can you please help me to achieve same speech to text recognition. I am also using the same code as CodeChanger written for speech recognition. I will be thankfull to you. Whatever link you mention not working